# When uploading assets what determines the maximum file size?

Tags: assets, config

When I upload an asset I get an alert window stating my file size is to large. I have increased the file size in the general.php config file larger than the file size, however I keep getting a error. We are using AmazonS3. Is Craft limiting the file size, PHP or AmazonS3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's most likely PHP. Most PHP installations come standard with a 2M limit.

Check out this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php) for more information on what needs to be adjusted.

Comment: It was indeed PHP.  Does Craft's "maxUploadFileSize" work on top of PHP's?

Comment: Yes, it appears so. Per Brad's answer: _"... Craft's own [maxUploadFileSize](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#maxUploadFileSize) config setting, which we default to 16MB."_

Answer (score 14):

**Craft** itself, limits the filesize only in the [`maxUploadFileSize`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#maxUploadFileSize). Default: 16MB

However Craft gets limited by:

**PHP:** Has a few values which might cause the problem:

- [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)
- [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)
- [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
- [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

**AmazonS3:** If not limited by a [`policy` value](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434), the default is 5GB.

**User:** Sometimes it can be just a Browser issue causing the problem.

Comment: So if you upload a file go S3... PHP MaxUploadFileSize, Memory Limit, Max_Input_Time and Post_max_Size dont count? You can upload up to 5GB?

Comment: @JohannesLamers, I'm curious to that as well. Did you find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 11):

It's almost always an environmental limitation.  The most common culprits are:

1. PHP's memory_limit setting: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit
2. PHP's post_max_size: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
3. PHP's upload_max_filesize https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

These default values vary per host/installation, but try increasing them in your php.ini file. You may or may not need to restart your web server in order for the new settings to take affect.

For your specific case, if those aren't the culprit, then I'd check either S3's upload limitation settings or Craft's own [maxUploadFileSize](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#maxUploadFileSize) config setting, which we default to 16MB.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else interested my issue was not the PHP limit but a limitation of NGINX, there is a setting which needs increased from the default value to allow uploading of larger files, client_max_body_size.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that f you're running a [multi-environment config](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs), and have configured your local environment (i.e. craft.dev) to point to a remote database, you'll need to make any php.ini changes on your local machine.

You can find the location of your php.ini file with `php --ini`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but I had to update the settings in Plesk, as rules being set elsewhere were being ignored. Someone may have a similar set up to me, and this will save them a few minutes of head-bashing.