# Does Craft enforce a maximum filesize for large files?

Tags: assets, upload, files

A client we're working with has a requirement to upload one large file (about 320MB) every 2–3 months. Craft has been configured with a local asset source to handle this.

I'm trying to decide the best way to approach this: whether we upload this large file via SFTP for them when required, or if the client can do this through Craft in their own time.

[This previous question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/492/when-uploading-assets-what-determines-the-maximum-file-size/) provides some good pointers. I've increased the necessary settings, however when attempting to upload a test file (315MB), Craft displays an alert ‘The file “testfile.zip” could not be uploaded, because it exceeds the maximum upload size of 128.0 MB.’

I haven't seen any filesize limits of 128MB, so is this value hardwired into the file upload logic? To confirm that the changed settings do work, a test file of 100MB was uploaded fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing Craft enforces is the [maxUploadFileSize](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#maxUploadFileSize) config setting, which by default is set to 16MB.  Outside of that, any limitations you run into will be environmental/server config related.